# Preparing bollinger bands with postgresql - STDDEV and PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a pet project on cryptocurrency and Bollinger Bands, and I'm stuck on a problem I'm not able to solve.

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.dataset
(
    "From_symbol" character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "To_symbol" character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Timestamp" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "Open" numeric(18,9),
    "High" numeric(18,9),
    "Low" numeric(18,9),
    "Close" numeric(18,9),
    "Volume_From" numeric(18,9),
    "Volume_To" numeric(18,9),
    "Weighted_Price" numeric(18,9),
    "Id" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('dataset_id_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT dataset_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("From_symbol", "To_symbol", "Timestamp")
```

If I run the following query

```
SELECT "From_symbol",
        "To_symbol",
        "Timestamp",
        "Open",
        "High",
        "Low",
        "Close",
        "Volume_From",
        "Volume_To",
        "Weighted_Price",
    AVG("Close") OVER
        (PARTITION BY "Id"
            ORDER BY "Id"
            ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SMA20,
    AVG("Close") OVER
        (PARTITION BY "Id" 
            ORDER BY "Id" 
            ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +
        STDDEV_SAMP("Close") OVER
            (PARTITION BY "Id"
                ORDER BY "Id"
                ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) * 2 AS "Upper_Bollinger_Band",
    AVG("Close") OVER
        (PARTITION BY "Id" 
            ORDER BY "Id" 
            ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -
        STDDEV_SAMP("Close") OVER
            (PARTITION BY "Id" 
                ORDER BY "Id" 
                ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) * 2 AS "Lower_Bollinger_Band"
    FROM public.dataset;
```

I get a null result on both the upper and lower bollinger bands.

While I have a very large dataset (2012-2020), I provide you with a sample of 40 lines. This should be enough in case you wish to test it.

```
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2011-12-31 08:52:00', 4.390000000, 4.390000000, 4.390000000, 4.390000000, 0.455580870, 2.000000019, 4.390000000, 1);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2011-12-31 16:50:00', 4.390000000, 4.390000000, 4.390000000, 4.390000000, 48.000000000, 210.720000000, 4.390000000, 2);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2011-12-31 17:59:00', 4.500000000, 4.570000000, 4.500000000, 4.570000000, 37.862297230, 171.380337530, 4.526411498, 3);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2011-12-31 18:00:00', 4.580000000, 4.580000000, 4.580000000, 4.580000000, 9.000000000, 41.220000000, 4.580000000, 4);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-01 05:16:00', 4.580000000, 4.580000000, 4.580000000, 4.580000000, 1.502000000, 6.879160000, 4.580000000, 5);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-01 16:28:00', 4.840000000, 4.840000000, 4.840000000, 4.840000000, 10.000000000, 48.400000000, 4.840000000, 6);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-01 23:45:00', 5.000000000, 5.000000000, 5.000000000, 5.000000000, 10.100000000, 50.500000000, 5.000000000, 7);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-02 21:04:00', 5.000000000, 5.000000000, 5.000000000, 5.000000000, 19.048000000, 95.240000000, 5.000000000, 8);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 12:45:00', 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 2.419172930, 12.869999988, 5.320000000, 9);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 15:22:00', 5.140000000, 5.140000000, 5.140000000, 5.140000000, 0.680000000, 3.495200000, 5.140000000, 10);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 15:54:00', 5.260000000, 5.260000000, 5.260000000, 5.260000000, 29.319391630, 154.219999970, 5.260000000, 11);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 16:32:00', 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 29.302457470, 155.010000020, 5.290000000, 12);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 18:10:00', 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 11.285444230, 59.699999977, 5.290000000, 13);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 18:14:00', 5.140000000, 5.140000000, 5.140000000, 5.140000000, 0.020000000, 0.102800000, 5.140000000, 14);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 18:26:00', 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 11.000000000, 58.190000000, 5.290000000, 15);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-03 18:27:00', 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 5.290000000, 4.010814660, 21.217209551, 5.290000000, 16);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 05:17:00', 4.930000000, 4.930000000, 4.930000000, 4.930000000, 2.320000000, 11.437600000, 4.930000000, 17);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 06:05:00', 4.930000000, 4.930000000, 4.930000000, 4.930000000, 9.680000000, 47.722400000, 4.930000000, 18);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 13:41:00', 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 2.641618500, 13.710000015, 5.190000000, 19);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 13:57:00', 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 8.724470130, 45.279999975, 5.190000000, 20);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 16:39:00', 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 5.190000000, 16.344726030, 84.829128096, 5.190000000, 21);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 16:53:00', 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 0.186090230, 0.990000024, 5.320000000, 22);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 16:54:00', 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 5.320000000, 10.394736840, 55.299999989, 5.320000000, 23);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 17:00:00', 5.360000000, 5.370000000, 5.360000000, 5.370000000, 13.629422720, 73.060000006, 5.360461812, 24);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-04 18:51:00', 5.370000000, 5.570000000, 5.370000000, 5.570000000, 43.312195780, 235.747069370, 5.442972011, 25);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 02:40:00', 5.720000000, 5.720000000, 5.720000000, 5.720000000, 5.000000000, 28.600000000, 5.720000000, 26);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 04:52:00', 5.750000000, 5.750000000, 5.750000000, 5.750000000, 5.200000000, 29.900000000, 5.750000000, 27);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 08:19:00', 5.750000000, 5.790000000, 5.750000000, 5.790000000, 14.800000000, 85.500000000, 5.777027027, 28);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 09:58:00', 6.000000000, 6.000000000, 6.000000000, 6.000000000, 2.236666670, 13.420000020, 6.000000000, 29);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 10:03:00', 6.000000000, 6.000000000, 6.000000000, 6.000000000, 0.168482700, 1.010896200, 6.000000000, 30);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 10:48:00', 6.150000000, 6.150000000, 6.150000000, 6.150000000, 10.000000000, 61.500000000, 6.150000000, 31);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 11:08:00', 6.190000000, 6.190000000, 6.190000000, 6.190000000, 0.571890150, 3.540000029, 6.190000000, 32);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 11:10:00', 6.190000000, 6.230000000, 6.190000000, 6.230000000, 16.000000000, 99.285718902, 6.205357431, 33);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 11:48:00', 6.230000000, 6.250000000, 6.230000000, 6.250000000, 14.000000000, 87.420000000, 6.244285714, 34);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 12:20:00', 6.460000000, 6.460000000, 6.460000000, 6.460000000, 0.773993810, 5.000000013, 6.460000000, 35);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 12:21:00', 6.460000000, 6.460000000, 6.460000000, 6.460000000, 0.178018570, 1.149999962, 6.460000000, 36);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 12:28:00', 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 0.311041990, 1.999999996, 6.430000000, 37);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 14:07:00', 6.440000000, 6.440000000, 6.440000000, 6.440000000, 0.310559010, 2.000000024, 6.440000000, 38);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 14:38:00', 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 0.466562990, 3.000000026, 6.430000000, 39);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 15:31:00', 6.420000000, 6.420000000, 6.420000000, 6.420000000, 0.311526480, 2.000000002, 6.420000000, 40);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-05 23:50:00', 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 6.430000000, 0.311526480, 2.003115266, 6.430000000, 41);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 00:35:00', 6.440000000, 6.440000000, 6.440000000, 6.440000000, 0.466562990, 3.004665656, 6.440000000, 42);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 00:39:00', 6.470000000, 6.470000000, 6.470000000, 6.470000000, 0.952012380, 6.159520099, 6.470000000, 43);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 00:41:00', 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 20.777443610, 138.170000010, 6.650000000, 44);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 00:43:00', 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 1.466275650, 9.750733073, 6.650000000, 45);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 00:46:00', 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 0.499265780, 3.320117437, 6.650000000, 46);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 07:02:00', 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 6.650000000, 1.425497660, 9.479559439, 6.650000000, 47);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 07:04:00', 6.690000000, 6.730000000, 6.690000000, 6.730000000, 6.310000000, 42.363858320, 6.713765186, 48);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 14:20:00', 6.800000000, 6.900000000, 6.800000000, 6.900000000, 9.310559010, 63.611801268, 6.832221481, 49);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 16:21:00', 6.760000000, 6.760000000, 6.760000000, 6.760000000, 0.295857990, 2.000000012, 6.760000000, 50);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 16:36:00', 6.500000000, 6.500000000, 6.500000000, 6.500000000, 0.500000000, 3.250000000, 6.500000000, 51);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 16:37:00', 6.490000000, 6.490000000, 6.490000000, 6.490000000, 1.540832050, 10.000000005, 6.490000000, 52);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 17:37:00', 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 0.500000000, 3.200000000, 6.400000000, 53);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 18:59:00', 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 1.550387590, 9.922480576, 6.400000000, 54);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 19:00:00', 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 0.838759680, 5.368061952, 6.400000000, 55);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 19:42:00', 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 6.400000000, 9.110852730, 58.309457472, 6.400000000, 56);
INSERT INTO public.dataset VALUES ('BTC', 'USD', '2012-01-06 21:18:00', 6.300000000, 6.300000000, 6.300000000, 6.300000000, 0.500000000, 3.150000000, 6.300000000, 57);
```

Would you be so kind as to let me understand what am I doing wrong? I traced the problem to the STDDEV usage, but I have no clue on why the PARTITION BY clause works on AVG and fails on the STDDEV.

I'm running PostgreSQL 12.2 on Ubuntu:

```
PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
```

Thanks!

Comment: For those readers who are not traders, you should probably tell us what a Bollinger Band is, and also include the expected output.

Comment: A Bollinger Band determines how much volatility the value is subject to. It determines three indicators: SMA20, or Simple Moving Average and an upper and lower limit, calculated combining the SMA20 with the STDDEV20 to determine volatility above and below the moving average. Volatility is based on the standard deviation, which changes as volatility increases and decreases. The bands automatically widen when volatility increases and contract when volatility decreases.

for more information http://tomaslind.net/2013/11/12/bollinger-bands-in-t-sql/

I expect both bollinger bands not be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this logic;

```
AVG("Close") OVER
    (PARTITION BY "Id"
------------------^
     ORDER BY "Id"
     ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS SMA20,
```

Your `id` is a unique value on each row so the partition ha only one row -- and the standard deviation of a single value is not defined.

Presumably, you intend:

```
AVG(close) OVER
    (PARTITION BY from_symbol, to_symbol
     ORDER BY timestamp
     ROWS BETWEEN 19 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS SMA20,
```

Notes:

- Do not enclose identifiers in double quotes.  That just makes it harder to write queries.
- Why are you using a sequence when you can simply use `generated always as identity`?
- Use the timestamp for ordering rather than the id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your results ? do the averages look right to you ?
I say this because your Id is unique and if you `PARTITON BY` on it, you will get 1 row partitions. While you can average 1 row, you cannot compute the standard deviation for one single row.

My suggestion would be to remove the `PARTITION BY "Id"` from all your aggregate functions. It seems you want to use the whole table as 1 partition anyway, or find the right column to partition by. A good candidate might be the `From_symbol`,`To_symbol` pair as you do not want to mix exchange pairs. So my suggestion would be to `PARTITION BY "From_symbol","To_symbol"` but you know the data best.